# Volume rendering question

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics

I have already prepared a skeleton and a skin. I am currently learning OpenGL. I want to know how I can extract the iso-surface of the skeleton and the skin and make the skeleton visible under the semi-transparent skin.

How can I set two thresholds for the skeleton and the skin, and extract the isosurface when scanning the voxels from back-to-front? Once a voxel that crosses the threshold is found, I can compute the normal vector by finite difference.

Finally, I can compute the colour by diffuse reflection: N *(0, 0, 1) where N is the normal vector, * is a dot product, and (0,0,1) is the vector towards the camera. Blend the colour of the skeleton and the skin to make the skeleton appear behind the semi-transparent skin. I know the idea but don't know how to implement it in C++ and OpenGL.

Comment: Are you attempting slice-based volume rendering or raycasting?

Comment: These are excellent questions. Volume rendering is not directly supported by OpenGL, as it only deals with rasterizing triangles/quads/polygons. One can shaders to implement a volume raycaster. Or one extracts the isosurface (with 3rd party code) then feds this to OpenGL. Maybe you split this question: "How to implement a volume raycaster using OpenGL fragment shader", tagged OpenGL, and "How to extract isosurfaces from volume data", tagged 3d-graphics.

Comment: What do you mean by "I have already prepared a skeleton and a skin", by the way ? In what form exactly, with what kind of software ?

Answer (score 2):

The "bible" for real-time volume graphics is [this book](http://www.real-time-volume-graphics.org/).  It covers GPU/shader implementation of volume rendering very well although arguably that approach is almost obsolete these days, and you'd be better off directly implementing the algorithms directly in CUDA/OpenCL.

Some of the introductory material in this [tutorial](http://www.voreen.org/240-Vis08-Tutorial.html) (IEEE Vis 2008) might also be useful to you.

Comment: That really is an excellent book for getting up to speed on volume rendering.

Answer (score 0):

There are other good tutorials for volume rendering,such as 《Efficient Volume Visualization of Large Medical Datasets》。Many people use OpenGL、GLSL ,too.

In addition ,many visualization system is online:

[ImageVis3D](http://www.sci.utah.edu/cibc/software/41-imagevis3d.html)

[Voreen(open source)](http://voreen.uni-muenster.de/)